# Map Struct causing unhandled exception error?

Tags: c++

So I've got the following in my code:

`Window.hpp`

```
class Window {
    struct windowMap {
        SDL_Window* window = 0;
        const char* title = 0;
        int width;
        int height;
        int flags;
    };

    typedef std::map<std::string, windowStruct*> windowMap;

    windowMap* m_windowMap;
};
```

`Window.cpp`

```
bool Window::init() {
    m_windowMap = new windowMap();
    (...)
};

SDL_Window* Window::getWindow(std::string id) {
    windowMap::const_iterator keyValuePair = m_windowMap->find(id);

    // check if the ID was found
    if (keyValuePair != m_windowMap->end()) {
        return keyValuePair->second->window;
    }

    SDL_LogError(ERROR, "Could not get window");
    return 0;
};
```

Now Intellisense does not throw any errors at all, and neither does the compiler but when I run the program, I get an unhandled exception error thrown:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x/*Quite a long address here*/ in SDL2-CutePlanet.exe 0xC0000005:
Access violation reading location 0x/*Quite a lot of 'F's here*/
```

The culprit seems to be `getWindow();` but I don't understand and know what is causing it to trip?

Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure m_windowMap isn't null when you call getWindow?

Comment: My guess is that `keyValuePair->second` is `null` or undefined and you are trying to access `window` property. This suppose that you called `init` before `getWindow` and so m_windowMap isn't `null`

Comment: @dwcanillas I don't think it is as when I call Windows init(), I get the created primary window.

@JeromeL The latter is true. I do call Window's init() first, and then in my Renderer class, to initialise my renderer I then call `window.getWindow();` (<-- I haven't made it that far as the error is getting in the way).

Comment: EDIT: so it's the `windowMap::const_iterator keyValuePair = m_windowMap->find(id);` line that's causing the access violation error. Any ideas?